# CSS Hover with scrollable element doesnt work in newer Chrome browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am running the following fiddle

[View here](https://jsfiddle.net/kncpfz50/1/)

Which is using a simple hover trigger to show the content

```
ul li:hover > ul
{
    display:block
}
```

It creates a drop down on hover and if there are too many items a scrollbar appears.

This works fine in IE and Firefox but I notice if the scrollbar is moused over in chrome it kills the hover state before you get to scroll the items. Seems to be an issue in later Chrome browsers as in Chrome 55 it works as expected but on Chrome 56.0 (.2924) this happens.

I don't want to specifically introduce JS to solve this was hoping to have everything managed in CSS.

Can anyone see issues with why this hover state isn't being honored?

Thanks

Comment: I have Google Chrome 56.0 and the fiddle you posted works perfectly. The code looks fine to me too. Did you try to replicate this on other machines?

Comment: Chrome 56 here too. I can confirm this is working. Try and re-install your browser if you don't find a resolution.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your feedback - we have several machines running chrome and any on the 56 build all act the same - as you approach the scroll bar the dropdown collapses

I will reinstall chrome on one of the machines but as several of our machines using 56 are acting the same it does seem strange

Comment: I remember reading a similar question here a couple days ago, and it turned out this was a bug in chrome introduced recently. (Sorry, don’t remember enough specifics to find that particular question right now, but I remember someone linked to a bug report on the chromium bug tracker. Perhaps try searching there.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in Chrome 56 where hovering over a scrollbar does not cause a hover event for that element. It will be fixed for 57. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=686678