# Hover over scrollbar is not being detected in Chrome (possibly all webkit based render engines)

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck in list item styling.

When i hover on body i'm showing list item box. List item shows properly but when hover on scroll bar hover effect get removed.

```
body:hover li {
    color: red;
    max-width: 100px !important;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 138px;
}
```

here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8datrxzy/)

Comment: what is your question exactly? because when i test it it works as expected?

Comment: @Christophvh the scrollbar is not being detected as hovered. (Well for me at least in Chrome)

Comment: aha yes, my bad :)

Comment: @danishfarhaj I guess you came across Chrome bug, that probably should get fixed.

Comment: @danishfarhaj http://stackoverflow.com/a/42159984/7581087

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this... There seems to be problem with hover not being detected over non HTML DOM element(scrollbar - ? correct me if i am wrong). jQuery mouseenter/mouseleave should do the trick.

```js
$(".container li").mouseenter(function(){
 $(this).addClass("hovered");
}).mouseleave(function(){
 $(this).removeClass("hovered");
});
```

```css
.container{
  display:inline-block;
}
li{
    max-width: 100%;
    transition:max-width .5s;
    transition-delay:.5s;
    overflow-x: auto;
    max-height: 138px;
}
li.hovered{
    color: red;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-width: 100px !important;
    transition-delay:0s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <li id="PrescriptionNo7107"> asdf sdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdfasdf sdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf sdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdfasdf sdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf sdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdfasdf sdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your CSS (not supported in Firefox & IE).

```
body li::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: .5em;
}
body li::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: darkgrey;
}
```

Comment: IE, Edge and Firefox don't seem to have that problem anyway.

Comment: I have suggested the title to be changed to `Hover over scrollbar is not being detected in Chrome (possibly all webkit based render engines)` To me it looks like an actual unintentional browser bug

Comment: Good title suggestion. 
Regarding the unusual behaviour of browser, perhaps that's how the browser events are bound.

Comment: i don't think so... Even when you move the :hover to the scrolling element's parent (and looking with Dev Tools at box border - wrapping around even the scrollbar part), it will bug the same... I don't believe that is intended behaviour.